# How to get the string value of a class when pressing enter in IPython?

Tags: python, ipython

In IPython, typing the name of a class and hitting Enter displays the class's fully-qualified name. How do I programmatically access this name as a string? It's not the same as what `str()` and `repr()` return, and because this is a class, not an instance of that class, defining its magic methods `__str__` and/or `__repr__` wouldn't help.

Already been to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37715461/what-built-in-function-is-called-when-entering-object-in-interactive-python-shel), but it's about the default Python interpreter, not IPython.

```
In [1]: class MyClass:
   ...:     pass
   ...: 

In [2]: MyClass
Out[2]: __main__.MyClass

In [3]: str(MyClass)
Out[3]: "<class '__main__.MyClass'>"

In [4]: repr(MyClass)
Out[4]: "<class '__main__.MyClass'>"
```

What method should I call on `MyClass` so I can get the same output when pressing enter on a class object?, `__main__.MyClass`, as a string?

**As someone suggested this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020014/get-fully-qualified-class-name-of-an-object-in-python) which I was already aware, but I am asking the question here is more curious about what internal method was called when hitting "enter" on a class object.**

Comment: The other answers are about the regular Python shell, which you aren't using. It looks like that's just showing you the fully-qualified name of the class, as used by the inherited `object` `__str__`, which is basically `f"{c.__module__}.{c.__qualname__}"` (see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/2020014/3001761).

Comment: @G.Anderson I updated my question, the `c` is not an instance, but a class. I guess the `magic functions` don't apply?

Comment: What interpreter are you using?

Comment: @CrazyChucky ipython

Comment: What do you mean by "string value of a class"? Can you simiplify your example more to focus on the question at hand. You seem to have a bunch of extra stuff that isn't relevant to this question.

Comment: sorry should have said `dot notation of the class`

Comment: So you're asking not how to get the same output, but how the internal implementation of IPython, specifically, generates it?

Comment: `'.'.join((MyClass.__module__, MyClass.__name__))` ?

Comment: Maybe the answer I was looking for was could be: "It's just how ipython does it "magically" against a class object when entered"

Comment: Well, "magically" is relative. But one would probably have to look at IPython's source code (or ask a developer) for a definitive answer.

Comment: `from IPython.display import display; display(MyClass)` seems to do what you want in an IPython shell, but that doesn't work in a regular shell when calling the same function. `sys.displayhook` as mentioned by Tim Peters in the post you linked to is probably the key (at least the [docs](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/2/api/generated/IPython.core.displayhook.html) mention "a generalization of the `repr()` of an object".

Answer (score 2):

For any practical purpose, it's `str(MyClass)[8:-2]`.